# how to create vertical list of panels in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap 3 i'm trying to create a list of vertical panels as can be seen on this [link](http://www.lawsitesblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/VerdictSearch-Filter.jpg) for the search results filters. It has one main panel and multiple panels inside this main panel.  I m trying the following html and styles but unable to create the desired layout of panels. Any ideas ? thanks

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-3">
    <div class="panel-heading">Refine Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- Default panel contents 1 -->
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading 1</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- Default panel contents 2 -->
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading 2</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a missing div, and you should probably do your column definition in a parent div tag to fix the formatting issues. Here is a JSFiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hbqau1h6/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><!-- Added containing column definition -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Refine Search</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <!-- Default panel contents 1 -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading 1</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <!-- Default panel contents 2 -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading 2</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- Missing div here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2>Search results</h2>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's ridiculous this answer doesn't have enough upvotes. You made my day!